# 401k Contributions + Employer Match be greater than Maximum Contribution?

Tags: united-states, 401k, contribution, limits, employer-match

This year, 401k contributions are capped at $17,000 per person.

So let's say somebody contributes this amount and is matched maybe 8% by their employer each contribution period.

Can the total amount be greater than $17,000? At 8% match, I think it would be $18,360.

The reason I ask is because for tax deduction purposes, the person did only contribute $17,000 and can only deduct $17,000 from income taxes, whereas their employer matched the rest.

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: The 17K limit is for people under age 50. The limits do not depend on single or married.

Comment: Generally an 8% match is not 8% of the contributions but 8% of the salary. Frequently it will be expressed as X% match up to y%; for example: 50% match up to 8%. In that case if you put in 2% they match with 1%, if you put in 8% they put in 4%, if you put in 12% they put in 4%.

Comment: FYI [Can a year-end true-up employer match exceed the 401(k) maximum contribution, in which case the employee would past of their 401(k) contributions?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/97599/5656)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The employer contribution is not considered income, thus is not included in the employee's contribution deduction limit. It is affected by an additional limit, not just the 17K. [According to the IRS](http://www.irs.gov/Retirement-Plans/Plan-Participant,-Employee/401%28k%29-Resource-Guide---Plan-Participants---Limitation-on-Elective-Deferrals), the total of your and your employer's contributions can be up to 100% of the salary or $50K, the lesser:

> **Additional limits.** There are other limits that restrict contributions
>   made on your behalf.  In addition to the limit on elective deferrals,
>   annual contributions to all of your accounts - this includes elective
>   deferrals, employee contributions, employer matching and discretionary
>   contributions and allocations of forfeitures to your accounts - may
>   not exceed the lesser of 100% of your compensation or $49,000 for 2011
>   and $50,000 for 2012.

Comment: The IRS sets the limits, but some employers do put a maximum cap as a percentage of each paycheck. This generally only impacts people in the company for part of the year.

Comment: @littleadv Always useful to quote some relevant text from the source link, because a page linked to may change or, worse, disappear.